# laravel Blade {{ }} or {!! !!} statement

Tags: laravel

On laravel documentation, they use `{{ }}` but not `{!! !!}` for Blade statement.
But some people said they prefer `!!` over `{{`.

What's the reason of using `!!`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{{ Escaped variable }}

{!! Unescaped variable !!}
```

Quote from the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data):

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's `htmlentities` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want
>   your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> `Hello, {!! $name !!}`

Comment: `{{ }}` is more secure.

Answer (score 2):

`{{ }}` will escape all special characters to prevent xss attacks, meanwhile `{!! !!}` will give You raw results.

`{{ "<script>alert('hi');</script>" }}` ==  `&lt;script&gt;alert(&#039;hi&#039;);&lt;/script&gt;`

`{!! "<script>alert('hi');</script>" !!}` == `<script>alert('hi');</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Please read [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data)

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Though be extra careful while using the later.